# SPARQL Query in Protégé (for individuals)

Tags: sparql, protege, querying

I am trying to execute a query by using SPARQL Query in Protégé.
I simply would like to see which individuals are related to which class.

When I simply write:

```
SELECT ?individual ?class 
WHERE { 
    ?individual rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual .
    ?class rdf:type owl:Class .
}
```

It brings me individuals BUT without respect to the classes (or inferred classes).
I checked the previous (related) questions but could not retrieve a sufficient answer for my simple issue. What I should write in the query so that only related classes are displayed after the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query consists of two triple patterns which are not connected by any variable:

The query should be

```sql
SELECT ?individual ?class 
WHERE { 
    ?individual rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual .
    ?individual rdf:type ?class .
}
```

I hope you understand the idea, if not I suggest to read a SPARQL tutorial which explains the concept of pattern matching.